# problem with repeater

Tags: asp.net, asprepeater

while i am running this code an exception is occuring at <%Eval("Firstname")%>.. the exception message is "Databinding methods such as Eval(), XPath(), and Bind() can only be used in the context of a databound control."
what to do..my code is as follows

```
<div>This is repeater
         <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
         <HeaderTemplate>
         <table>
         <tr>
            <th>FirstName</th>
            <th>LastName</th>
            <th>City</th>
          </tr>
         </HeaderTemplate>
         <ItemTemplate>
         <tr>
         <td><% Eval("FirstName")%></td>
         <td><% Eval("LastName")%></td>
         <td><% Eval("City")%></td>
         </tr>
         </ItemTemplate>
         <FooterTemplate>
         </table>
         </FooterTemplate>
         </asp:Repeater>
         <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
             ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:NorthwindConnectionString %>" 
             SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Employees]">
         </asp:SqlDataSource>
    </div>
```

Comment: your are supposed to type it like `<%# Eval("Firstname") %>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are missing the `#` symbol

try:

```
<%# Eval("FirstName") %>
```

Comment: @Hop...ya its true....how blindly i done that...really i am feeling bad.. thank you dear

Answer (score 2):

To have the data emitted through databinding you should use the [data-binding expression syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178366.aspx)

```
<%# Eval("FieldName")%>
```

Comment: FirstName is the column name of the employee table

Comment: It's an example. The "FieldName" should be replaced by each field's name. :-)